# How to identify failed drive/port on 3ware card

Tags: linux, raid, 3ware

I have a 3ware 9650-SE controller with 2 drives in RAID-1 configuration. The drive on "port 1" has an error but the drive cages aren't labeled. I tried using the cli to "identify" the drive but tw_cli just spits out "N/A". I thought this might blink the drive activity LED but no:

```
# tw_cli /c7/p1 set identify=on
Setting port Identify on /c7/p1 to [on] ... N/A
```

How can I blink the drive activity of the individual port to find out which drive in the array is the one which is bad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found a way to do it using the "show all" command on a shell loop:

```
# while [ 1 ] ;do  tw_cli  /c7/p0 show all; done
```

This creates sufficient access to the individual drive (p0) to blink the light on the drive bay.

Comment: Same problems here… Thanks for the neat workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Now, if you happened to inherit a Windows Server with a 3ware RAID card, you can do something similar with powershell:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> while ( 1 ) { tw_cli /c7/p0 show all }
```

And, when you have replaced the drive and want to see the rebuild status, you can use the same trick to get something similar to the ***watch*** command in Linux:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> while ( 1 ) { clear ; tw_cli info c7 ; sleep 5 }
```

HTH.